# SwiftUI - Image offset preview issue

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a navigation view which is a root view. After user login I would like to show Welcome View where I want to show user's image and user name.

Currently preview is a bit different to my device screen:
[image]

You may noticed that there is a Login back button on the simulator screen. Probably that's why I have the differences here.

Here is my code:

```
struct WelcomeView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userService: UserService
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image("MountainWelcomBackground").resizable().frame(height: 300).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)

            CircleImage(image: userService.user.image!)
                .offset(y: -220)
                .frame(height: 140)
                .frame(width: 140)

            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                HStack(alignment: .top) {
                    Spacer()
                    Text(userService.user.username)
                        .font(.headline)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            .offset(y: -200)

            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct WelcomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let userService = UserService()
        userService.user = User(username: "Alex Matrosov", email: "test.developer@gmail.com", avatar: nil, image: Image("ManPlaceholderAvatar"))

        return WelcomeView().environmentObject(userService)
    }
}

struct CircleImage: View {
    var image: Image
    var body: some View {
        image
            .resizable()
            .clipShape(Circle())
            .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 4))
            .shadow(radius: 10)
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
    }
}
```

How to make preview the same as on simulator? Probably I need to add Navigation view to preview somehow or maybe I set offset in a wrong way. Actually I just followed apple swiftui tutorial and they do this ui like me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Offset depends on parent container, which differs in your case for real app running in Simulator and Preview showing only Welcome view.

Here is PreviewProvided to have same

```
struct WelcomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let userService = UserService()
        userService.user = User(username: "Alex Matrosov", email: "test.developer@gmail.com", avatar: nil, image: Image("icon"))

        return NavigationView { 
            WelcomeView().environmentObject(userService) 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yea that's what I supposed too, but I did not know how to wrap it correctly. works great! thanks!!! you always help me)